# To check how many locks a thread has obtained in visual studio 2010?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2010

I am debugging a multi-thread program which is written by others and very big.
I doubt there could be a deadlock under some very rare condition.
How could I use vs 2010 tools or tools like windbg to identify how many locks a thread has had at a given time and the sequence that thread acquired those locks?

Comment: There is no built-in way for this. You should pause the application when you suspect it's in a deadlock position, then investigate the active threads' call stack to find the locks.

Comment: Sorry I am new to C++, but could you give any hints or links about how to find the locks by investigating the threads' call stack?

Comment: A deadlock is a situation where two or more threads are waiting for each other. By investigating the suspicious threads' call stack you can guess which ones are waiting and for what. It is not really a formulated procedure, just examine and guess.

Comment: So, when the program hang I attached a debugger to it and there are two threads both with the call stack starting with this: > ntdll.dll!_NtWaitForMultipleObjects@20()  + 0x15 bytes. 
Does this suggest it's a dead lock here?

Comment: @Nyaruko That's a wait for a signal. It doesn't have to be a lock: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Yochai Timmer Thanks for clarification, my situation is:
1. The process hangs up (very tiny chance)
2. It stopped at a thread with call:ntdll.dll!_NtWaitForMultipleObjects@20() + 0x15 bytes
3. In the Windows' event log, it says the program hangs because of a cross thread deadlock.
Will these information be sufficient to say that the program is in deadlock situation?

Comment: Not necessarily. There could be program that works signals, where it depends on a thread to signal another thread when there's work to do. The waiting thread will most like be waiting on WaitForMultipleObjects Until it gets a signal to continue. This is not a deadlock, just a thread starvation scenario.

Comment: So I can basically ignore the comment from windows' event log?

Comment: @Nyaruko No, just saying it doesn't have to be a deadlock, it could be waiting for an event. When windows decides a process "isn't responding" it's because the thread that's handling its message queue isn't responding to messages. So if that's happening you need to find the cause and fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[windbg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852365.aspx)** to get a list of locked locks, and their owning threads.
Just use the `!locks` command.

You can use windbg within visual studio as well:

[Visual Studio 2012 and WinDbg Integration](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mariohewardt/archive/2012/06/05/visual-studio-2012-and-windbg-integration.aspx)

Edit:

When a deadlock exists, you'll find a pair of threads (or a circular dependency of threads) that are all paused on a lock that is held by the another thread.

So you'll see **Lock1** held by `Thread1` , **Lock2** held by `Thread2`. But `Thread1` is waiting for **Lock2**, and `Thread2` is waiting for **Lock1**.

Comment: Hi, I have tried to use !locks, but it says: Unable to resolve ntdll!RtlCriticalSectionList
It seems the symbol is not found, how could I add the symbols?

Comment: File -> Symbol file path ... Select the directory where you have the .pdb files

Comment: And for microsoft stuff, you can use this command: .sympath+ SRV**http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols